# Does your app access location in the background in APKs or app bundles targeting Android 9 (Pie) or older (SDK level 28 or lower)?

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, mobile-development

I want to release my app to google play store with SDK level 29, shall I select yes or no for "Does your app access location in the background in APKs or app bundles targeting Android 9 (Pie) or older (SDK level 28 or lower)"?

The problem is it says “Does my app use location in the background with SDK level 28” answer is yes. However, the one I am submitting is with SDK29 and it doesn’t use location in the background so the answer is NO, but it’s not asking for the app with SDK version 29.

It's asking what it's doing with SDK28 which is irrelevant with the current version.

If the answer is wrong they will remove the app from the play store! Please advice.